# Does First-Come, First-Served (FCFS) Scheduling avoids deadlock?

Tags: operating-system, deadlock

Is it guaranteed that by using FCFS scheduling, the 'system' will not be in deadlock?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think that deadlocks have anything to do with FCFS. AFAIK, deadlocks occur due to threads (in most cases; Let's assume a thread A) hold on to resource locks while waiting to acquire locks of other resources, which are already locked by another thread B. And if the thread B is also waiting to acquire locks of the resources which are already held lock by thread A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The four conditions for a deadlock are:

1. Mutual exclusion: Irrespective of the scheduling algorithm, resources can be possessed by one process without sharing.
2. Hold and wait: In this condition, processes can wait for other resources while holding onto one resource. This is possible with any scheduling algorithm.
3. No preemption: FCFS is non-preemptive. That is, processes executing a critical section of their code cannot be forced to stop.
4. Circular wait: Processes are waiting for another process to release a resource in a circular fashion. This, again, is irrespective of the scheduling algorithm

Hence, FCFS does not guarantee that the system will not be in deadlock. If the four conditions are met, a deadlock will occur.

Answer (score 1):

Deadlocks are caused by resource locking, not scheduling order. FCFS doesn’t guarantee that your threads will always grab resources in sequence, so the answer to your question is no.